# Building and querying a sample general tree in Smalltalk

Tags: tree, smalltalk

Using the BTree package at SqueakSource (or any other you may know) and given the following tree

```
-Root
|
--Node1
|
--Node2
---Node21
---Node22
---Node23
----Node231
----Node232
-----Node2321
----Node233
|
--Node3
```

I've tried to write the following but without success:

- Build the tree
- Given Node23 answer its direct children
- Given Node2 answer all its children
- Given any Node, answer its parent
- Collect all the children

This is NOT homework, the reason why I'm asking for a basic example is because in the case of BTree, documentation is almost inexistent, and tests are not good enough for figuring out basic usage, actually examples are mixed with asserts and using convenience methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not so concerned with execution speed, there is an extensively documented package in SqueakSource for that purpose http://www.squeaksource.com/TreeLW.html which was originally released for VisualWorks.

One class you may use for building your tree is SKPVTreeLW, which supports value, subtrees, supertree, and a key. You may achieve your example implementing something like this:

```
t := SKPVTreeLW
    key: '1'
    value: 'N' 
    subTrees: { 
        ( SKPVTreeLW key: '2' value: 'A' ) .
        ( SKPVTreeLW key: '3' value: 'B' subTrees: { 
            ( SKPVTreeLW key: '31' value: 'C' subTrees: { ( SKPVTreeLW key: '311' name value: 'D' ) } ) .
            ( SKPVTreeLW key: '32' value: 'E' subTrees: Array empty ) } ) .
        ( SKPVTreeLW key: '4' value: 'F' ) .
        ( SKPVTreeLW key: '5' value: 'G' ) .
        ( SKPVTreeLW key: '6' value: 'H' ) }.
" Subtrees of node 'B' "
t recursiveDetect: [ : s | s value = 'B' ] 
        inclusive: true 
        topDown: true 
        breadthFirst: true.
" or searching by key "
t atKey: '3'
" Childrens as nodes "
t recursiveSubTrees: true.
" Direct children "
t values.
```

Answer (score 4):

A [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) is a sorted data structure associating keys with values. B-Trees allow you to handle huge amount of data and guarantee searches, insertions, and deletions in logarithmic time. The [BTree Package](http://www.squeaksource.com/BTree) on SqueakSource follows the protocol of a Smalltalk `Dictionary`:

- `at:` and `at:ifAbsent:` are used to search for values given a key,
- `at:put:` is used to insert a key and value pair, and
- `removeKey:` is used to delete a key.

Furthermore, all iterator functions you know from `Dictionary` are supported (`do:`, `keysDo:`, `valuesDo:`, `keysAndValuesDo:`, ...); as well as a few more to iterate over ranges of keys (`from:do:`, `from:to:do:`, `upTo:do:`, ...). Normally you shouldn't need B-Tree collections in your application code, unless you have a performance problem with the built-in `Dictionary` class.

It seems to me that you try to modify the inner workings of a B-Tree. You shouldn't do that, the `BTree` class reorganizes itself automatically to always provide the most efficient representation (this is mostly what the tests verify). If you want to manage your own tree, why not create your own `Node` class containing an `OrderedCollection` of the child nodes and a parent link?